# Making a variable in jquery 1.9.1 fails and in 1.8.3 doesn't

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-1.8, jquery-1.9

I just upgraded to 1.9.1
After some technical defiificulties all work except:

```
var $newthumbs = $('                <div id=\"car-7\" class=\"thumbnail_car thumbnail span2\" data-sorting-top=\"2\" data-sorting-date=\"2013-01-12 16:47:31 UTC\"></div>');
```

If I put this line in the console of jquery 1.8.3 it gets accepted and I can retrieve it with $newthumbs

in 1.9.1 it fails with `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

I've read the [changelog](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/) and I don't see anything relating that should break this. I may not know a lot of jquery, but this type of syntax looks standard.

What changed?

**Update**

I did find this [here](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/)

> HTML strings with leading whitespace: jQuery 1.9 restricts the strings
>   processed by $() for security reasons. Although we recommend you use
>   $.parseHTML() to process arbitrary HTML like templates, the 1.1.0
>   version of the Migrate plugin restores the old behavior.

Comment: why do you wrap that in $? If it's just a regular string you can just remove it.

Comment: Remove the gigantor space at the beginning, and it should work fine. `$.trim()` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the spaces, it will work:

```
var $newthumbs = $('<div id=\"car-7\" class=\"thumbnail_car thumbnail span2\" data-sorting-top=\"2\" data-sorting-date=\"2013-01-12 16:47:31 UTC\"></div>');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/KFmMQ/1/

Comment: Might be a trimming problem?

Comment: so jquery 1.9.1 doesn't allow spaces?

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be the case... for the time being, you can use a custom `trim()` function. I have provided you with one in this demo. Wish I could be more helpful! Let me know if you have any questions! Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/KFmMQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem are the whitespaces in the beginning of the string. I have no idea why this is a problem, but it obviously is.

By the way: You can remove the pointless backslashes:

```
var $newthumbs = $('<div id="car-7" class="thumbnail_car thumbnail span2" data-sorting-top="2" data-sorting-date="2013-01-12 16:47:31 UTC"></div>');
```

or you can use double quotation marks for the surrounding string:

```
var $newthumbs = $("<div id=\"car-7\" class=\"thumbnail_car thumbnail span2\" data-sorting-top=\"2\" data-sorting-date=\"2013-01-12 16:47:31 UTC\"></div>");
```

Comment: the thing is that these divs are automatically generated, so baskslash is the rails javascript escaping

Comment: then use the second option.