# Angular.js/jQuery html string parsing in 1.9.1 vs. 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-1.9, jquery-1.8

Trying to do `angular.element(stringWithHtmlStructure);` causes

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id="foo">bar</div>
```

in jquery 1.9.1, however it works in jquery 1.8.3

Is it an issue or a feature? Security one perhaps? How do I deal with it?

1.8.3 example http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYYKIixcYzOL46hq0puS?p=preview
1.9.1 example http://plnkr.co/edit/ETmQMY8KoCP0gaKdSrMD?p=preview

It's definitely not a problem with any of the angular stuff, doing `$(stringWithHtmlStructure)` fails just the same, as you can see here http://plnkr.co/edit/FqvOKZ62t0IJ57cT05ew?p=preview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817039/making-a-variable-in-jquery-1-9-1-fails-and-in-1-8-3-doesnt?rq=1 could it be this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is definitely with jquery 1.9.1

> HTML strings with leading whitespace: jQuery 1.9 restricts the strings
>   processed by $() for security reasons. Although we recommend you use
>   $.parseHTML() to process arbitrary HTML like templates, the 1.1.0
>   version of the Migrate plugin restores the old behavior.

way to deal with it is use any kind of trimming function, whether it's jquery's $.trim or underscores trim or even your own.

Note that this problem only occurs when trying to use template from $templateCache, if you use template or templateUrl attr on the directive it works fine, I guess angular internally trims it.

Answer (score 2):

If your string contains leading spaces you should remove them.

This should work:

```
angular.element($.trim(stringWithHtmlStructure));
```